# Отключать уже играющий трек при включении другого?

Tags: javascript, html5, аудио

[Тут](http://test.mahaev.com/audio-stack/) пример. Проблема более чем ясна. Необходимо отключать уже играющую мелодию при включении любой другой.
Как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как вариант, перед запуском нового трека делать `$('.audioplayer-playing audio')[0].pause()`. Надо только проверять что что-то действительно проигрывается, т.е. что `$('.audioplayer-playing audio')` что-то возвращает

Comment: Весь код, относящийся к проблеме должен быть в самом вопросе. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из возможных решений заключается в прослушивании события 'play' каждого из audio.
[Вот](http://www.sitepoint.com/essential-audio-and-video-events-for-html5/) неплохая статья (правда, на английском), объясняющая media events в html5.

На JSFiddle я конечно прокомментировал код, но если в двух словах, то:
1) Находим все audio элементы (`var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')`)
2) Преобразовываем в массив (`Array.prototype.slice.call(audios)`)
3) Добавляем event listener для каждого элемента (`audios.forEach(addEventListener)`)
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qajL2ze4/)

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог Вам. Удачи!